# query custom classes via FMDB

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am new with FMDB and sqlite.
i want to know is it possible to query custom classes via FMDB.

I cant understand the advantages of using FMDB over sqlite..
are there any added APIs and functionalities?

Can anyone help me understand how to use the custom functions of sqlite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FMDB is just a wrapper for sqlite.

Not sure what you mean by query custom classes, you can query whatever you've saved in the sqlite database

Comment: i want to know if there are any added advantages of using this wrapper?

Comment: Syntax is a lot cleaner than using it directly IMO

Comment: thanks @nick i was wishing there was some added functionality